# Can SAGE or othe software compute or guess growth rates of infinite discrete groups?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, geometric-group-theory, sagemath

I am interested in the growth rate of some finitely generated (infinite, non-abelian) discrete groups. Knowing very little about geometric group theory, I am wondering if I can plug them into sage and have it output estimate the (word) growth rate somehow.

I know theoretically I could write a program to do this, but since the naive algorithm I have in mind would take forever to run to any reasonable length (there are exponentially many words that need to be reduced...) I wondering if there are slicker methods out there.

Or perhaps I am being too naive - can the true growth rate of an arbitrary group take a long time to appear? (For the easy groups I can think of now, the growth rate is immediately apparent...)

Comment: It is actually provably not possible to write a program that can take a finitely presented group and a word as input and correctly tell you whether or not the word is the identity. It's undecidable.

Comment: That said, you could probably implement your naive algorithm in Sage (or perhaps better directly in GAP, one of the programs Sage uses to do group theory) to test some hypotheses - hopefully small cases would not run into the word problem *too* quickly...

Comment: It's likely you're not interested in any of the groups that have this problem, but it kind of throws a wrench into the possibility of a general algorithm.

Comment: Maybe look at FR package for GAP? See [this](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/fr-2.2.1/doc/chap11.html#X7BFF1432803C9172) in particular.